# What is the max wattage per sqft for heat floor wires?

Tags: radiant-heating, floorheating

I am wanting to use electric floor heating as my primary source of heat for a room we are remodeling.

My question is can I use more than 15 watts per sqft and still be within national building code requirements?

The spacing I want to use for the heating wire is going to be approximately 18 watts per sqft. Will that work??

Comment: The installation instructions should provide the cable spacing. The cable must be installed according to the MFG. Example if using a 12 watt per sqft cable the spacing can not be reduced to increase the heat.

Comment: So it sounds like it's not a code issue it's an MFG issue. So my only option is to ask the MFG for all the specs?

Comment: Unless you basically have no insulation, higher power shouldn't be necessary or helpful. It also increases the risk of overheating the floor before the room gets up to temperature.

Comment: Code states that the equipment be installed to the manufacturer's instructions.

Comment: Thanks! I understand and that helps answer the question! Thanks again!